# Changing column names in list elements

Tags: r

I have a huge list with data.frames (same number of columns, different number of rows).
I succeeded to use apply - instead of the for loops I learned to avoid - to create a mean value over specific columns in each list element with

```
t2<-lapply(t1, function(x) cbind(x,rowMeans(x[,c("ColumnX","ColumnY","ColumnZ")])))
```

The problem I am stuck with now is the new columns name. It is "rowMeans(x[,c("ColumnX","ColumnY","ColumnZ")])".

How can I change this for all list elements? My poor "lapply"-knowledge was not sufficient for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two ways to do this, and it actually has to do with the `cbind` function and not the `lapply` function:

```
cbind(x,DesiredName = rowMeans(x[,...]))
```

Or after you've cbind'ed:

```
> names(x)
[1] "Column X" "Column Y" "Column Z" "rowMeans(x[,...])"
> names(x)[4]
"rowMeans(x[,...])"
> names(x)[4] <- "DesiredName" ###Assign a name to the fourth column
> names(x)
[1] "Column X" "Column Y" "Column Z" "DesiredName"
```

That's obviously the long way, but it useful for if you forget to name something during the `apply` or `cbind` process.

Comment: The first hint does the job when I use it in the `lapply` term. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a colname, for example `RowMeans`

```
t2 <-lapply(t1, function(x) cbind(x,RowMeans=rowMeans(x[,c("ColumnX","ColumnY","ColumnZ")])))
```

Actually you can accomplish your goal using this alternative:

```
lapply(t1, function(x) transform(x,RowMeans=rowMeans(x[,c("ColumnX","ColumnY","ColumnZ")])))
```

Here `RowMeans` is the name of the new variable containing each row mean.

Comment: I do not understand the `transform` and the last, shorter solution: The thing is, that I do not want to create rowMeans over the complete row, but only over three columns... which is accomplished by your first solution. Thank you for that.

Comment: @JochenDöll I was wrong, actually I thought your list consisted of only three cols, so the 2nd and 3rd solution did not work. I had to make some assumptions since you didn't provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I've just edited my answer to take into account your desired output. If you want to get to know what `transform` does you have to make a little effort and read the help file by doing `?transform`